# Less not compiling in Webstorm 7

Tags: css, node.js, compiler-construction, less, webstorm

I have an issue with LESS File watcher in Webstorm, doesn't want to compile into CSS.

I tried every possible websearch and advice during the last two days with no results.

- Nodejs is installed correctly I believe, Path is set in the Enviroment variables (without the "\" at the end)
- less module is installed as global (I used "npm install -g less")
- path to C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\npm is set too
- File Watcher was prompt automatically in Webstorm so I just clicked "add file watcher".

After this it looks like Webstorm is actually trying to create the css file (with every change I can see the message "Executing LESS task" at the bottom), but doesn't create it.

I tried reinstall nodejs twice (I am using Windows 7 x64, Webstorm 7.0.1), I tried changing less compiler to this one (http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&pluginId=7177) and this one (https://github.com/acdvorak/intellij-lessc-plugin), I tried different settings for all of them (Track only root files, create output file from stdout). I tried every possible combination and restarted my computer I don't know how many times in between... The css file is never created and I get this issue:

non_object_property_loadError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined in PathToMyWebsite\style.less on line null, column 0:

I tried different projects, even the ones that worked before and I get the same error message so I am positive my .less file is ok.

What did I miss? Maybe it is just a stupid rookie mistake but I just don't know where am I going wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Please keep in mind that I am not a professional programmer, I am comfortable only with html/css so if I need to change something in code please be as specific as possible, thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a support ticket. Sample project (with .less file that shows up the problem and file watcher configured) would probably help. BTW, can you compile .less in cmd console? cd to your project folder and execute 'lessc.cmd --no-color <your file>.less' - does it work?

Comment: compiling in cmd console will throw basically the same error:

SyntaxError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined in <my project folder>\style.less on line null, column 0:

I will create the support ticket, thank you lena

Comment: UPDATE: I found the problem, I had one of less mixins set up badly. Interesting is that I copied it and applied from another (functional!) project. What is even more interesting - when I copied it again it worked, but only when I changed parameters it stopped working (5px for 4px in box-shadow).

Comment: You could put your solution as an answer and then accept it. Then the question wont remain as open and unanswered in the queue...